# How to ensure that anonymous FTP has been disabled on a Solaris 10 system?

Tags: security, solaris, ftp, group, authorization

What line in which configuration files in the `/etc/ftpd` directory do I have to check to ensure that anonymous FTP has been disabled?

From my understanding now, to ensure that anonymous FTP is disabled, all the users assigned to the `anonusers` group in `/etc/ftpd/ftpaccess` has to be added to `/etc/ftpd/ftpusers` to deny them access.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3):

Adding `guestserver` to the ftpaccess file should disable anonymous FTP:

```
# echo "guestserver" >> /etc/ftpd/ftpaccess
```

Test it out by ftping to localhost and use `anonymous` as the user login; you should see it fail.:

> 530 Guest login not allowed on this machine.
>   Connection closed by remote host.

Comment: From an audit POV, what is the best way to test that anonymous access has been denied?